# Для чего нужен belongsToGraph в этом коде?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class functionxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        double y = scan.nextDouble();

        boolean belongsToGraph =Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) == 1;

        if (belongsToGraph) {
            System.out.println("Точка (" + x + ", " + y + ") принадлежит графику функции.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Точка (" + x + ", " + y + ") не принадлежит графику функции.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ни для чего, в `if` можно сразу вставить выражение, без присваивания промежуточной переменной.

Comment: Смотрите как в данном случае изящно выглядит тернарный оператор                                
String result = (Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y)==1?
                "Точка (" + x + ", " + y + ") принадлежит графику функции.":
                "Точка (" + x + ", " + y + ") не принадлежит графику функции.");

            System.out.println(result);

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае использование такой переменной выглядит как попытка применить один из принципов чистого кода, а именно дать переменной **содержательное имя**:
[Хабр: «Чистый код» Роберт Мартин. Конспект...](https://habr.com/ru/articles/485118/)

> **Имена должны передавать намерения программиста**
>
> Имя переменной, функции или класса должно сообщить, почему эта переменная существует, что она делает и как используется.

То есть, введение отдельной булевой переменной несколько упрощает понимание логики и/или предназначения кода без излишних комментариев:

```java
// принадлежит ли точка графику |x|+|y| = 1
if (Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) == 1) {
   // ...  
}
```

Разумеется, в *данном примере* такое именование может показаться излишним, о чём указал в своём комментарии @Byb, так как необходимая информация "о предназначении" и так "продублирована" в последующем коде (сообщениях, выводимых на консоль).